# Hide Camera Messages in terminal

Tags: c++, computer-vision, stdout

When I am using my camera in OpenCV there are several messages appearing in the terminal like:

```
mm40api: XIMEA Camera API V4.05.02
mm40api: Adding camera context: dwID=45405451  ptr=64049000 processID=000008DF
mm40api: Enable sensor
mm40api: Frequency 114 71
mm40api: Enabled 1 bandwidth 48000000
mm40api: Time needed to read BPL:150ms
mm40api: Successfully parsed BPL file, 1264 total corrected pixels
mm40api: SetGPIO 1 set to 8
mm40api: Frequency 50 31
mm40api: Enabled 1 bandwidth 48000000
mm40api: SetGPIO 1 set to 0
mm40api: AutoSetBandwidth measurement
mm40api: CalculateResources : Context 64049000 ID 45405451 m_maxBytes=512 m_maxBufferSize=524288
mm40api: AutoSetBandwidth measured 360Mbps. Safe margin 10% will be used.
mm40api: Current bandwidth limit auto-set to 324 Mbps (min:80Mbps,max:360Mbps)
mm40api: Frequency 50 31
mm40api: Enabled 1 bandwidth 40500000
mm40api: Frequency 42 29
mm40api: Enabled 1 bandwidth 40500000
mm40api: Frequency 42 29
mm40api: Enabled 1 bandwidth 40500000
mm40api: Frequency 21 14
mm40api: Enabled 1 bandwidth 40500000
mm40api: CalculateResources : Context 64049000 ID 45405451 m_maxBytes=512 m_maxBufferSize=524288
mm40api: StartVideoStream
mm40api: WorkerThread is up
```

Is there a way to hide these messages?
Thanks.

Comment: These are probably coming from the underlying API or driver. They are not OpenCV messages. Beyond redirecting or filtering stderr and/or stdout there probably not much you can do (from OpenCV).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Probably it would be best to redirect that into a log file. Is there a (good) way to redirect the camera's output only? Best would be to do this device dependent but I guess that may be easily complicated.

Answer (score 0):

These are probably coming from the underlying API or driver. They are not OpenCV messages.

Beyond redirecting or filtering `stderr` and/or `stdout` there probably not much you can do (from OpenCV).

Standard stream redirection and/or filtering is usually platform dependent but with the least hassle.

I guess you can filter out all lines starting with `mm40api:`. But again, this is just for your particular camera/driver.